# Rail return custom blank field error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How could you return a custom message for blank fields in rails?

```
validates_presence_of :name, :description, :message => "Please fill in the required fields."
```

This returns two instances of the error message if both are blank. I just want it to return once.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, the accepted way to set the humanized names and custom error messages is to use locals ([For more reference click here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models))

```
# config/locales/en.yml
    en:
      activerecord:
        attributes:
          user:
            email: "E-mail address"
        errors:
          models:
            user:
              attributes:
                email:
                  blank: "is required"
```

Now the humanized name and the presence validation message for the "email" attribute have been changed.

Validation messages can be set for a specific model+attribute, model, attribute, or globally.